# How to find information about devices in Linux

Tags: system-information

I want to find the following information for devices in Linux:

- Bus speed (e.g. 66 MHz)
- IRQ settings
- Vendor identification
- AGP rate (e.g. 1x, 2x, 4x)
- MAC address

I am only able find the last one  by `/sbin/ifconfig  | grep HWaddr`

How can I find this information in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lspci` as root with different verbosities (`-v` to `-vvv`); the most verbose setting will show bus speeds and IRQ (I don't know about the AGP rate - no machines with AGP graphics here).

E.g.

`lspci`:

```
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

`lspci -v`:

```
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 53
I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
Memory at f1804000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at f1800000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

`lspci -vvv`:

```
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 53
Region 0: I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
Region 2: Memory at f1804000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
Region 4: Memory at f1800000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Address: 00000000fee0100c  Data: 41b2
Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 01
    DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
    DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 4096 bytes
    DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
    LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <512ns, L1 <64us
        ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
    LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
    LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
    DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
    LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
    LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
         EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Vector table: BAR=4 offset=00000000
    PBA: BAR=4 offset=00000800
Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Unknown small resource type 00, will not decode more.
Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
    UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
    CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
    AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
Capabilities: [140 v1] Virtual Channel
    Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
    Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
    Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
    Status: InProgress-
    VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

For the MAC address can use `ifconfig` as you're doing or `ip link | grep link`.